# Installing python 3.6 , when I am already using Anaconda Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, anaconda, spyder

I am currently using Anaconda2 . 
python -V gives :- Python 2.7.11 :: Anaconda 4.0.0

**Now I want to use Python 3.6** and i tried to update my python version using the following command in anaconda:-

**conda install python=3.6
but this did not worked** , because I work in a restricted environment MNC .

Two Options are  available to me and I want to know which one should I follow

1> I can install Anaconda3 . 
But if do that , do i need to uninstall already existing version of Anaconda I am using i.e Anaconda2 ? If not please tell me how will I choose which version of python to use in Spyder.

2> I can install Python3.6 .
If I take this option , I have no idea of what to do afterwards.

P.S.:- I am not very good at installation so please guide me in the easiest way possible.

Also if there is some other way , please share that too

Comment: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you able to create a new environment with the command:

```
conda create -n py36 python=3.6
```

?
if so, anaconda will create a new subfolder for this environment in the anaconda/envs folder named py36. in spyder you can go to tools->preferences->python interpreter and choose the python interpreter (python.exe if on windows) in that folder. to use pip and all in the commandline for that environment write:

if on linux/mac:

```
source activate py36
```

if on windows:

```
activate py36
```

then continue to do you installations and all.

Comment: Thanks , it is working perfectly fine, but i am not getting an IPython Console. The following error shows up:-                                                              An error ocurred while starting the kernel
Either:
Your IPython frontend and kernel versions are incompatible or
You don't have IPython installed in your external interpreter.
In any case, we're sorry but we can't create a console for you.                            
                                                                                                               
 Any idea how can i solve this?

Comment: have you tried the command  conda update ipyton inside the py36 environment (e.g. after activate py36) ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at environments, which enable you to have multiple python versions and manage them seperately. The documentation can be found [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)

In short, just do:

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.6
```

to create an environment with python 3.6. You can enter it doing

```
source myenv
```

and then `pip install` any desired packages.

Comment: it should be `source activate myenv`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Anaconda and python, you just update it with:-

1. Open Anaconda Prompt type:-

   ```
   conda update conda

   conda update python
   ```
2. Check your python version `python --version`  and conda version `conda --version`